# Cannot paste a command to vim 8.0

Tags: vim, cygwin, clipboard

In vim 8.0 when I try to paste a vim command from clipboard, it behaves as if vim was in insert mode: the command is pasted into the file itself instead of being executed.

I'm using mintty. Mouse is off. Same result when pasting from the terminal's context menu or using a hotkey.

Comment: It works for me in command mode. If you are not in command mode it paste as insert mode.

Comment: I WAS having the same problem, though for me it started after patching my Fedora 25 system. I have been pasting VI and VIM commands for more than 30 years and find this change of behaviour very annoying... Link to my question, 
and the solution.... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364047/stop-vim-pasting-selections-as-text

Answer (score 2):

Vim 8 added support for "bracketed paste" (wherein the terminal wraps pasted text in escape codes which indicate to vim that the text is a paste vs a typed string;
 see [Patch 8.0.0210](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/T5Wz9rI2yZg)). It seems like the default behavior is to automatically enable insert mode before accepting pasted text.

You can disable bracketed paste and go back to the old behavior by adding `set t_BE=` to your vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

I usually manually type the `:` to get the command prompt, *then* paste the command in.  Vim doesn't care that a command starts with a double `::`.

Comment: Only works for a single vim command line.   I often paste 200+ vim commands in one single paste, to do major reformatting of thousands of files.

Comment: @anthony The user in the question asked for a way to "paste _a_ command", not 200.  Also, for 200 editing commands, you're better off saving them in a separate Vim script and then executing _that_. This would additionally give you the opportunity to review the commands, change them etc.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, And a detailed solution has also been given,
explaining not only how you can stop this (using `set t_BE=`) but also how you can stop it just for the vim 'command mode' allowing you to paste using 'paste mode' from 'insert mode'.

Link to my question and answer... [Stop vim pasting selections as text!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364047/stop-vim-pasting-selections-as-text)